# Confuse how to use Repo Authoritative mode on HHVM using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: php, hhvm, hacklang, hiphop

I just tried to build some website using hack lang developed by facebook, and found an interesting feature called **Repo Authoritative**.

I had tried to follow the official docs : https://docs.hhvm.com/hhvm/advanced-usage/repo-authoritative

But still no progress.

Here are my **server.ini** config file :

```
; php options

pid = /var/run/hhvm/pid

; hhvm specific 

hhvm.server.port = 9000
hhvm.server.type = fastcgi
hhvm.server.default_document = index.php
hhvm.log.use_log_file = true
hhvm.log.file = /var/log/hhvm/error.log
hhvm.repo.central.path = /var/run/hhvm/hhvm.hhbc
```

Did anyone have a better explanation on how to use this repo thing ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! - I'm afraid questions asking for tutorials are not welcome here!

Comment: Hi, okay then, question edited sir.

Comment: This is still not a useful question -- what did you try? What was the output of those commands? Why do you think it's not working? You need to provide a lot more information for us to help you, otherwise the best link I have is the documentation you already linked to.

Comment: I'd love an answer to this question... repo authoritative mode is very poorly documented...

Comment: exactly @wulftone :(